# Using mutate and starts_with

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to change the value of certain variables depending on whether they start with a certain string-sequence.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("12345", "12345", "12345", "23456", "23456"))
df %>% mutate(var2 = ifelse(starts_with("123"), "ok", "not ok"))
```

All values starting with "123" should be changed into "ok". How can I combine `starts_with()` with `mutate()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(var2 = case_when(str_detect(var1, '^123') ~ 'ok',
                TRUE ~ 'not ok'))
#   var1   var2
#1 12345     ok
#2 12345     ok
#3 12345     ok
#4 23456 not ok
#5 23456 not ok
```

---

Or with `ifelse` in `base R`

```
ifelse(grepl('^123', df$var1), 'ok', 'not ok')
#[1] "ok"     "ok"     "ok"     "not ok" "not ok"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("12345", "12345", "12345", "23456", "23456"), 
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

`starts_with` is used to select columns which start with a particular name. Here you can use base R `startsWith` instead.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(var2 = ifelse(startsWith(var1, "123"), "ok", "not ok"))

#   var1   var2
#1 12345     ok
#2 12345     ok
#3 12345     ok
#4 23456 not ok
#5 23456 not ok
```

However, we can also do this in base R and without `ifelse`.

```
df$var2 <- c('not ok', 'ok')[startsWith(df$var1, '123') + 1]
```

Or with `grepl`

```
df$var2 <- c('not ok', 'ok')[grepl('^123', df$var1) + 1]
```

**data**

`startsWith` need data to be character, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("12345", "12345", "12345", "23456", "23456"), 
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```